# How to change order of list items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, list

Here I have a navigation items in a list which are in the specified order. I'm using JavaScript to change the order based on the condition. But I'm unable to get the order I'm trying to achieve.

actual order

```
Nav01
Nav02
Nav03
Nav04
Nav05
mynav
```

expected nav order

```
mynav
Nav01
Nav02
Nav03
Nav04
Nav05
```

What i'm getting

```
Nav02
Nav03
Nav04
Nav05
Nav01
mynav
```

html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-menu__item-link nav-menu__item-link--level-1 d-block d-lg-inline-block text-uppercase">Nav01</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-menu__item-link nav-menu__item-link--level-1 d-block d-lg-inline-block text-uppercase">Nav02</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-menu__item-link nav-menu__item-link--level-1 d-block d-lg-inline-block text-uppercase">Nav03</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-menu__item-link nav-menu__item-link--level-1 d-block d-lg-inline-block text-uppercase">Nav04</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-menu__item-link nav-menu__item-link--level-1 d-block d-lg-inline-block text-uppercase">Nav05</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-menu__item-link nav-menu__item-link--level-1 d-block d-lg-inline-block text-uppercase">mynav</a></li>
  </ul>
```

JS:

```
  var country = "NZ"
  
  if(country === 'NZ'){
    var firstMenuItem = $('a.nav-menu__item-link.nav-menu__item-link--level-1:contains("Nav01")').parent();
    var mynav = $('a.nav-menu__item-link.nav-menu__item-link--level-1:contains("mynav")').parent();
    mynav.before(firstMenuItem);    
  }
```

Comment: Are you looking to always move last to first, or are you targeting a specific link text? It seems like you're trying too hard.

Answer (score 1):

`.before(content)` inserts content that is specified by parameter (in your case it is `firstMenuItem`) and inserts it before elements in a set you are calling method for (in your case it is `mynav`).

So, if you want to use `.before`, you need to swap context and parameter like this:

```js
firstMenuItem.before(mynav)
```

Please note, that if your intention is to move `mynav` to start of the list, it is better to specifically do so, in case items in your list would change their default positions. It can be achieved with `mynav.prependTo(target)` method, where `target` is your list.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS.
There's no need to use JavaScript in order to *just* change the position of a last element - to first.
Assign the parent a class and use [**CSS flex and `order`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

```css
.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.nav-list li:last-child {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-list">
  <li><a href="#!">Nav01</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Nav02</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Nav03</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Nav04</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Nav05</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">mynav</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Ordering flex items (*MDN*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Ordering_flex_items#the_order_property)